# OpenGL getting projection matrix

Tags: python, opengl, matrix

I am trying to use gluUnProject in OpenGL, first I need to get the projectoin, model_view, and viewort matrices. According to examples that I have found online I used

```
 glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection)
 glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model_view)
 glGetInteger(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport)
```

But I get the error "ValueError: glGetFloatv requires 1 arguments (pname), received 2: (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, [])"

So, what should I be using to get these matrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
projection = glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)
# and so on ...
```

after that in `projection` variable should be PROJECTION matrix

Comment: Good point. The default C bindings for `gl...v` functions always take a pointer to a memory location to store the result and "return" `void`. Python bindings don't need to be passed said pointer, as explained [here](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/opengl_diffs.html). This changes the function signatures for most `glGet__(...)` functions.